# Command to check the 'linker' used(by clang++) for executable creation on Mac OS

Tags: clang++, lld

I have an executable created using 'clang++' compiler(using mac os 10.9 sdk) on mac os.

```
$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-241.9
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 3.5svn

$ sw_vers
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion: 13F1911
```

My query is how to confirm(command to check) if my executable is created using ld.lld linker or ld.gold/some other linker? What is the default linker 'clang++' uses(command to cross-check) on mac os?

Regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 2):

Pass `-v` to see the subcommands clang runs. Pass `-###` to only see the subcommands and make clang not actually run them.